# Set up a project runner in Teamcity to deploy build artifacts to Artifactory

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, teamcity, artifactory

In our web-application we manage our continuous integration using TeamCity. So far we have manually added required jars and used an ant script to build and deploy our application. Lately we switched to Maven and added Artifactory to the cycle.

I need to know how to deploy our build artifacts from TeamCity to Artifactory.
I added the Artifactory plugin to TeamCity (following [this](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/TeamCity+Artifactory+Plug-in) guide) but when trying to add a new build step I can't seem to find any Artifactory related step (which I expect to find).

Am missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is a separate step but actually a set of options at the end of the Maven build step itself (it should be toward the bottom).

See here for more detail:

- http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/TeamCity+Artifactory+Plug-in.

Specifically, it says "The 'Deploy maven artifacts' option will only be available when using a 'Maven2' build runner."

Comment: Ok thank you. I still don't get something -  where does the team-city artifactory plugin comes in? How should I use it?

Comment: At the end of the Maven build, the plug-in will push the built artifacts into Artifactory.  You would use this approach in lieu of the mvn deploy:deploy command.  The plug-in helps by controlling authentication (you may want to limit who can publish artifacts) and can save you some configuration effort in the individual poms.  You can even use the plug-in to exclude certain artifacts.  In general, it is more flexible than mvn deploy:deploy.

Comment: Artifactory Team City plugin provides two main advantages: Build Info creation and atomic deploy.
Build Info is the metadata about your build. It contains all the details about built artifacts, used dependencies, environment variables etc. This metadata is passed along the uploaded artifacts and availble in Artifactory. Here are the details: http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration

Comment: Another benefit of Arifactory plugin kicks in when you use it for deploying. Instead of executing 'deploy' maven task use 'install' and leave the deployiment to the plugin. By doing that you'll achieve atomic deploy - all the artifacts will be uploaded to Artifactory only after a successful build, as opposite to maven:deploy which deploys after each module.

Comment: Thanks you! I think I get the idea now :)